# Python int-byte efficient data structure

Tags: python, data-structures

i am currently storing key-values of type int-int. For fast access, I am currently using an BTrees.IIBTree structure stored in memory. It is not stored on disk at all since we need the most recent data.

However, the current solution barely fits into memory, so I am looking for a more efficient database or data structure in terms of access time. In case it would be stored in memory it also needs to be efficient in terms of memory space.

One idea would be to replace the BTrees.IIBTree structure with a int-byte hash written in C as an extension for Python, but the data would still be lost in case the machine fails (not a terrible thing in our case).

What are your suggestions?

Comment: Are the keys contiguous or sparse?

Comment: The keys are hash codes of some text, so they are not consecutive values.

Comment: You can try using redis http://redis.io/ or some similar project.